# hover over image frame effect not working in firefox .15

Tags: css

I used a simple css effect that frames an image and changes the frame color on hover over. Despite the effect working perfectly on ie9 and chrome, the effect is jittery on firefox, it just kinda sticks on the hover over and only works if you hover from below the image with your mouse? and the frame color change sticks on effect mode, very messy looking. Anyone have an idea on how to correct this for firefox. the css is pretty striaght forward

```
.highlightit img{
    border: 4px solid #FFCCFF;
 }

.highlightit:hover img{
   border: 4px solid #f35c93;
   }

.highlightit:hover{
   color: red; /* Dummy definition to overcome IE bug */
 }
```

Sorry I tried to enter the html code, but it's not being accepted.

Many thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example? http://jsfiddle.net/ is useful.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are setting the hover on the element with the class highlighit. This element may not have the same height as the img and therefore may not appear to hover on the whole image. so make sure it has the same height or is the right display

Comment: i think jquery hover might be useful so that you can apply the effect on multiple divs

Comment: @MalSu its very great of you ...

Comment: Hi folks. Malsu Ill go back and look into your comments on previous posts, Thanks for pointing that out, I was very wet behind the ears when I asked those questions, and did not know about the forums etiquette. The page I refer to is http://www.amorame.com/Babydolls.html in regards to the image size and element, all is in order there, this should not be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @LEOPM Sorry about snappish, wasn't my intention. I'm afraid I can't help though, I don't think I can open lingerie sites at work, haha.

Comment: lol, cant argue with that, nothing too dangerous in there though ;-)